# Ammo count Xna / Monogame

Tags: xna

I'm trying to minus 1 from the Player Ammo every time the spacebar is pressed.

However anytime I press the space bar, it subtracts a lot more then one from the Player Ammo int.

Here's my code:

```
int player1Ammo = 5;
```

Retrieve the current state of the keyboard:

```
KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
KeyboardState _previousKeyboardState = keyboardState;


if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
           {

                player1Ammo -= 1; FireBullet();

            }
```

How do I fix that issue I'm getting?

Answer (score 1):

In your case *if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))* mean not "*if* Space pressed". It mean "*while* Space pressed", becouse game call Update method 60 (by default) times per second. You cannot press and release button faster then 1/60 second, so while it pressed each time this expression will be true. And each time it repeat your code.

Do it like that:

```
class Game1 : Game
{
    private bool isKeyPressed;

    void Update()
    {
        KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            if (!isKeyPressed)
            {
                isKeyPressed = true;
                // do what you need when key pressed
            }
        }
        else if(keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
        {
            if (isKeyPressed)
            {
                isKeyPressed = false;
                // do what you need when key released
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update

[My own solution on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/utils/src/747965a9b740cbd030275588a87eeedb22ead61f/GameHelper/Input/?at=master) (write me if link will be broken).

Create instance of CustomKeyInputManager, register keys you want and update it every frame. Check when keys pressed, released, hold and so on.

Comment: I'd recommend making (or finding) a completely separate class for handling the states of the keyboard, so you can just do a KeyboardManager.Update(time) every update, and check for presses with KeyboardManager.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space). Which is essentially what this little piece of code does, just limited to the space key.